# Getting error: ld: framework not found Fabric for architecture armv7 in App

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, ios-frameworks, google-fabric

I have build a iOS framework eg: **abc.framework**. Now in abc.framework I have added FirebaseDatabase and FirebaseMessaging. The abc.framework compiles and builds properly. However when I add the abc.framework and abc.bundle in my iOS project eg: **xyz.project** then it is giving error "**framework not found Fabric for architecture armv7**". I have **not added Fabric in abc.framework** and not in my xyz.project. However when I **remove the Firebase** from the **abc.framework** then t**he error disappears** from **xyz.project** and the project **compiles and run without errors.**

If anyone has encountered the same issue then please let me know how should I solve the issue. I have to **integrate Firebase in abc.framework** and that framework will be added in **xyz.project**

Answer (score 0):

Nested frameworks are not allowed in IOS , it's only allowed in MacOSX , to create a frameWork it must be of a pure code , fabric is in Firebase ,  also framework must support all architecture armv7,64 and soon on this configured when you build it, I encountered the same situation posted in Apple forums and find that

[image]

Comment: So I will have to add Firebase in framework(abc.framework) and In App(xyz.project) also??

Answer (score 0):

If CocoaPods is an option for you, the recent CocoaPods 1.4.0 release has added the `static framework` [podspec option](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#static_framework), which enables the definition of static frameworks that allow depending upon other static frameworks like `Fabric`.

Comment: This also didn't work...Any other suggestion is welcome